# .net6 Lambda with Proxy+ Route

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, .net-6.0

I have two Lambda functions and a single API gateway with two routes, `/external` and `/portal`. They both route to two different Lambda functions, however we are getting a 404 back ground we believe the lambda as the .net6 code doesn't handle the routes correctly.

Here is our setup;
[image: Routes]

I know both lambdas work as i have routed both of them using a default route to test.

What I believe to be happening is that the .net code is expecting the routes to start at the root of the domain path `/my-routes/in-dotnet`. But in reality as the request comes through apigateway the actual route ends up being `/external/my-routes/in-dotnet`.

How do you handle this in .net6 to allow proxy+ routing to work.